# Openpyxl: how to delete duplicates in an excel file while adding another value in another column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm asking is how do you use panda to make the expected out put 
so if this is the spread sheet I'm doing

```
    Name Total
    Bruce $240
    Selina $800
    Bruce $600
```

i need the output to be:

```
    Name Total
    Bruce $840
    Selina $800
```

My question is how would i do that with pandas

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
groupby(Name)
loop the group 
    write new dataframe for instance with the sum of group Total
```